# How do I include the currency conversion block in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I have attached a screenshot of an example Paypal Express Checkout payment page which include some currency conversion information (indicated with a blue arrow).  I am trying to replicate this implementation of Paypal Express Checkout on my own app.  What parameters or settings are used to set whether to show this information or not?  It is not clear in the documentation.  Note: I am using Classic APIs

[image: Paypal Express Checkout]

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/

Comment: The link you have provided seems to refer to the Paypal API for getting exchange rates and not for Paypal Express Checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Only PayPal Adaptive Payment have [Currency Conversion API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/).
Express checkout does not have.

If you really want to use PayPal Currency Conversion, you can still use this API. But, additionally you need to send "APP-ID" in your request. For Sandbox APP-Id is constant which is`APP-80W284485P519543T`.for live, you need to create a APP from apps.paypal.com to get the APP-ID and then send the request.